# Can anyone tell how to generate random colors for the background for websites using css?Is it possible?

Tags: html, css

like we can use random images using unsplash image source. Similarly can we do it for background colors using css only??
If yes can anyone tell how to do it?

well i used random function to generate random colors for the background in styling. But it didnt give any output

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code which you have tried so far.

Comment: What random function did you try to use?

Comment: To inject some randomness in CSS you need something outside CSS which is random - e.g. like the timing of the first user click - as there is no built in CSS function for random.

Comment: i just tried like how i generated in app development  just now i came to know that there is no builtin function as such for random function:(

Comment: Not yet. There is a [planned feature for random() in CSS](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values-5/#random) but no browser support currently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would require at least some JS  to generate colors at random

```js
const container = document.getElementById('element');

generateRandomColor();

function generateRandomColor() {
  // 16777215 is decimal equivalent of FFFFFF in hexadecimal
  const randomHex = Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
  container.style.backgroundColor = `#${randomHex}`;
  container.innerHTML = `#${randomHex}`;
}
```

```css
.container {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 24px;
}
```

```html
<div id="element" class="container"></div>
<button onclick="generateRandomColor()">Generate Random Color</button>
```

Comment: thanks so it means i cant generate random colors without using js ryt?

Comment: SASS has a random function but you'd need to use that preprocessor if you just wanted to avoid JS https://sass-lang.com/documentation/modules/math/#random

Comment: I am not very sure about that @blogger10